# Yarn install command in node.js is throwing 'Failed to replace env in config' error, how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I am having this problem, with yarn dependencies.

Wen i run yarn intall i am getting ths:

> `yarn workspace v1.22.19 error An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${npm_GEd*************************}". info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\bruno\\Desktop\\Superprops\\yarn-error.log". info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.